# How to handle duplicate keys when importing data using bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am running this code:

`bcp (Table) IN (Location of Input File) -T -n`

How do I skip this one error
`Duplicate Key`

I would like to keep using BCP. I know I saw a `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` but do not know how use it in BCP.

Comment: You would remove a `unique` or `primary key` constraint on the table.

Comment: That is something I have to do in SQL or can I do it BCP when I run that script?

Comment: It's common to "stage" your bcp into a database so that you can cleanse it. If you had a table w/o constraints that matched the target table, you could bcp the data into that staging table and then select the unique data into your target table. BCP is a blunt instrument :-)

Comment: I wrote a Truncate file to use to remove the data then bcp one bat file [link] http://www.nettrax.net/2011/05/26/sqlcmd-ms-sql-servers-command-line-interface/

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to do to fix this error and still use BCP and a Batch file. Please look at this link and what you do is `make a file->write your truncate SQL code` then you use the sqlcmd -E -i "path to truncate file" then all all your BCP commands after the SQLCMD in a batch file

[Link]http://www.nettrax.net/2011/05/26/sqlcmd-ms-sql-servers-command-line-interface/